# PHP: Validating Form When Routing

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I'm trying to validate a form that's being submitted through a PHP router.

All my traffic is sent to index.php via htaccess. to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /router

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /divbase/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

index.php then provides the appropriate content:

```
<?php

Router::get('/form', function() {
   include 'content/form.php';
});

?>
```

so when you go to `example.com/form`, the form page is loaded:

```
<?php

    $errorMessage = false;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (!isset($_POST['name']) || $_POST['name']=='') {
            $errorMessage = 'Please enter your name';
        }
        else {
           // do something with the data
           echo "Success!!";
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post">
   <input type="name" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<p><?php if ($errorMessage) echo $errorMessage; ?></p>
```

However, when I try to submit the form on that page it 404s. After doing some troubleshooting, it looks like the PHP thinks that the form is being submitted to `index.php` rather than `form.php`.

I've tried to set the form action to:

```
<?php "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>
```

But it still 404s. Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Comment: could you show your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another route for POST, for example...

```
Router::get('/form', function() {
   include 'content/form.php';
});

Router::post('/form', function() {
   echo 'Hello world';
});
```

Your form is using method="post" so you need to add a POST route

Comment: @user3143218 glad to help! Accept the answer as correct when you can.